# Refresh indices in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have deleted some rows in a pandas DataFrame, but in the new DataFrame the indices are not refreshed, i.e.
from this:

```
     id  marks
 1  123 45
 2  124 67
 3  127 89
 4  257 10
 5  345 34
```

I have obtained:

```
    id  marks
 2  124 67
 4  257 10
 5  345 34
```

While I want:

```
    id  marks
 1  124 67
 2  257 10
 3  345 34
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For default index is used [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) - index starts from `0` to `length` of index:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    id  marks
0  124     67
1  257     10
2  345     34

#if need starts index values from 1
df.index = df.index + 1
print (df)
    id  marks
1  124     67
2  257     10
3  345     34
```

Another solution is assign values to index:

```
df.index = range(1, len(df.index) + 1)
print (df)
    id  marks
1  124     67
2  257     10
3  345     34
```

The fastest is use [RangeIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#range-index):

```
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.index) + 1)
print (df)
    id  marks
1  124     67
2  257     10
3  345     34
```

**Timings** are really interesting:

```
In [19]: %timeit df.reset_index(drop=True)
The slowest run took 7.41 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 83.3 µs per loop

In [20]: %timeit df.set_index(np.arange(1, len(df)+1))
The slowest run took 7.06 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit df.index = range(1, len(df.index) + 1)
The slowest run took 13.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.5 µs per loop

In [22]: %timeit df.index = np.arange(1, len(df.index) + 1)
The slowest run took 11.54 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 26.9 µs per loop

In [23]: %timeit df.index = pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.index) + 1)
The slowest run took 14.43 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.07 µs per loop
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [26]: %timeit df.reset_index(drop=True)
The slowest run took 4.71 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop

In [27]: %timeit df.set_index(np.arange(1, len(df)+1))
The slowest run took 4.71 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 238 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit df.index = range(1, len(df.index) + 1)
The slowest run took 13.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 µs per loop

In [29]: %timeit df.index = np.arange(1, len(df.index) + 1)
The slowest run took 11.29 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.8 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit df.index = pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df.index) + 1)
The slowest run took 14.33 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.24 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.set_index(np.arange(1, len(df)+1))
```